# insertSubView:belowSubview: for a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiimageview, addsubview

I am woundering if its possible to use the insertSubView:belowSubview: As it stands the below code is throwing this warning error

```
Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIImage *__strong' to parameter of type 'UIView *'
```

I am hoping maybe I have done something slightly wrong you guys can see as the only other way I can think of doing this would be to put the UIImageView into a UIView... please tell me there is a better way.. lol

code below.

```
UIImage *shadowImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"shade.png"];
UIImageView *shadowImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:shadowImage];

[otherNav.view addSubview:shadowImageView];
[otherNav.view insertSubview:shadowImage belowSubview:animatedActionView];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
[otherNav.view insertSubview:shadowImageView belowSubview:animatedActionView];
```

because the first parameter must be an View or a subclass of uiview

in your case you try to pass  an UIImage who itsn't an UIView or subclass of UIview

Comment: opps.. my mistake. I also took out the stupid [otherNav.view addSubview:shadowImageView];... got myself abit mixed up there and just could not see it for the life of me.